# Unable to handle mysql error using async await

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, exception

I am new to node js. I learned am learning to execute MySQL queries using async/await instead of callback functionality.
I am able to get data on success but If any error occurs, I couldn't catch that error. Please suggest me how to achieve so.

**My MySQL code to create a row in the education table**

```
Education.create = async (newEducation) => {
    try {
        const res = await sql.query("INSERT INTO education SET ?", newEducation);
        return await {id: res.insertId, ...newEducation};
    }catch(err) {
    // I couldn't catch DUPLICATE ENTRY ERROR or any other MYSQL generated error
      console.log(": ---------------------------")
      console.log("Education.create -> err", err)
      console.log(": ---------------------------")
      return err;
    }
}
```

Comment: what are you awaiting in `return await {id: res.insertId, ...newEducation};` this is already an object, it is not a promise that you can wait to to be resolved. Delete the await from it.

Comment: I did that but still i can't catch error